# Java 8 - how to process arrays of non-primitive types?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I'm using Google maps API and want to process search results. The result is returned as an Array of non-primitive types `PlacesSearchResult[]`.

I want to build an array of locations, `LatLng[]` represented by a latitude/longitude pairs using data from the places search results array.

Here is how I did it with Java 7:

```
PlacesSearchResult[] searchResults = placesSearchResponse.results;
int placesCount = searchResults.length;

    LatLng[] locations = new LatLng[placesCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
        locations[i] = searchResults[i].geometry.location;
    }
```

I decided to try using Java 8 here but got confused with how to process the arrays of non-primitives.
If it was an array of primitive types I would do something like this:

```
int[] a = ...
int[] result = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
.map(i -> a[i])
.toArray();
```

What would be the correct way to process the arrays of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a stream from the `searchResults`, `map` it to `LatLng`'s and then collect to an array as follows:

```
Arrays.stream(searchResults)
      .map(s -> s.geometry.location)  
      .toArray(LatLng[]::new);
```

As for your current solution, the problem with it is that instead of using `IntStream.map` you should use `mapToObj` as you're trasforming to object types and not primitive types then finish it off with specifying the type of the array elements in the `toArray` method. example:

```
IntStream.range(0, searchResults.length)
         .mapToObj(i -> a[i].geometry.location)
         .toArray(LatLng[]::new);
```